# Программа выдает NAN и с арксинусом

Tags: c++, математика

[image: Это мой пример, который я пытаюсь решит]

Со встроенным арксинусом программа выдает NAN и с 
моим арксинусом программа выдает NAN.

```
    void teylor2() {
    double x;
             cout<<"Vtoroe vyrazhenie \n Vvedite X( X<=0.5 и X>0 )"<<endl;
             if((cin>>x) == 0) {throw 100;}
             //cin >> x;
             //if (abs(x) > 1) throw 404;
             cout<<"Znachenie vyrazhenija: \n Razlozheniem v rjad:   " << 
  log10(x-3) * pow(ArcSin(5 * x),2)<<endl; /* тут я реализую свой арксинус он 
 ниже в описании, но и он не работает.*/
             cout<<" Vstroennymi metodami:  " << log10(x-3) *  pow(asin(5 * 
 x),2)<<endl;
    }
```

Мой арксинус

```
double ArcSin(double x) {
     if (abs(x) <= 1) {
         double y, k, a;

         k = 1.0;
         a = x;
         y = x;

         while (abs(a) > eps) {
             a = (factorial(2 * k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1)) / (pow(4, k) * 
 pow(factorial(k), 2) * (2 * k + 1));
             y += a;
             k++;

         }

         return y;
     }
     else return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Скажите, чему равно `x-3` при ваших ограничениях? От `-3` до `-2.5`, не так ли? И чему, по-вашему, равен логарифм от отрицательного числа?

Comment: извини, но я не знаю ограничений я предполагаю, что от -1 до 1.

Comment: Тогда обратитесь к учебникам...

Comment: Было бы интересно посмотреть все условие, а не одну строчку...

Comment: это все мое условие что у меня есть

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автору вопроса желательно освоить школьный курс математики.

Comment: Условие *какое*? Может, там написано "перепишите красивым почерком" или "наберите в MathType"? :)

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим область определения вашей функции.

Для логарифма это [image: введите сюда описание изображения], или [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для арксинуса [image: введите сюда описание изображения], или [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Таким образом, область определения функции представляет пустое множество. Откуда у вас такое веселое задание?...

Comment: а можете пожалуйста это вставить в мой код.

Comment: Что вставить? Что решения нет? :)

Comment: @Harry Ну почему сразу нет? Может, это задача из курса ТФКП, мы же не знаем. :)

Comment: @Yaant Тогда оно конечно... ну, если ТС скажет, что это так - поможем :) ("В военное время синус может достигать трех!" (с) Старый анекдот с военной кафедры)